# Store file structure in database

Tags: mysql, database, file, path, structure

I want to store the output of the Linux command `ls -lah` in a MySQL table and I want to know if there is an automated process or process to do this. I think it should store it with columns like file name, size, permissions, user or group for example. No matters the best language to do.

EDIT: I was thinking about use the 'tree' command and stdout to store it in a plain text file, after some format I can load in table as csv tab separated, maybe... that's my best option

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>>` in order to change the default output destination (stdout).